# Anyone have any idea about writing a program that works in the same fashion as a message composer in the old mobiles in C++?

Tags: c++

The program must receive integer input. When use enter 2 the program outputs letter ‘A’ and if 2 is pressed twice, the letter ‘A’ will disappear from screen and character ‘B’ will appear and if 2 is pressed thrice the letter ‘B’ will disappear and Letter C will appear. To enter ‘AA’ you have to enter number ‘2’ twice with delay. Delay must be as smaller as it is usually in the mobile.

A program that input a number like below and converts it into string. 28444333# The program will output ATIF If you have to print “AAA” then input will be 212121# where 1 is used as separator. # will be used as input terminator.

I've made a program using switch statements in a while loop. That is the maximum thing I've done so far.

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(){

    int x;
    while (1){
        cin >> x;
        switch(x){

    case 2:
        {
            system("CLS");

            cout << "A\n";
    break;
        }
    case 22:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "B\n";
    break;
        }
    case 222:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "C\n";
    break;

        }
        case 3:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "D\n";
    break;
        }
    case 33:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "E\n";
    break;
        }
    case 333:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "F\n";
    break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "G\n";
    break;
        }
    case 44:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "H\n";
    break;
        }
    case 444:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "I\n";
    break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "J\n";
    break;
        }
    case 55:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "K\n";
    break;
        }
    case 555:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "L\n";
    break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "M\n";
    break;
        }
    case 66:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "N\n";
    break;
        }
    case 666:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "O\n";
    break;
        }
    case 7:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "P\n";
    break;
        }
    case 77:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Q\n";
    break;
        }
    case 777:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "R\n";
    break;
        }
    case 7777:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "S\n";

    break;
        }
    case 8:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "T\n";
    break;
        }
    case 88:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "U\n";
    break;
        }
    case 888:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "V\n";
    break;
        }
    case 9:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "W\n";
    break;
        }
    case 99:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "X\n";
    break;
        }
    case 999:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Y\n";
    break;
        }
    case 9999:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Z\n";
        }
    break;
    case 0:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << " \n";
        }
    break;
    case 1:
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << ".\n";
        }

    break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe you should switch to `libc` calls `getc()`/`getchar()` as stream input would require pressing Enter after each symbol. Additionally, you need to wrap your `switch` statement in a loop, measure time between inputs, and make the condition more complex (it has to remember the previous key itself, the number of times and the last time it was entered)

Comment: I truly appreciate that GMichael! But the problem is I'm almost a rookie in C++ that's why what are you trying to say I'm not quite getting properly.

Comment: This is not a problem a newcomer to C++ should be tackling. Take away the delay requirements and it is trivial, but once you add that desire to measure delay between keystrokes it is not so trivial anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Input streams have no concept of delay between keystrokes. In order to acheive what  you describe in your description, you will have to rely on operating system dependent APIs such as

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and timers.

Comment: Yes I had a rough idea about doing so but didn't know what would be the syntax to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of pressed keys and delays between presses, you can use `::std::chrono` to measure time intervals.

```c++
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

...

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
int repeats_count{};
decltype(cin.get()) last_char{};
decltype(high_resolution_clock::now()) last_input_time{};
auto const max_delay{200ms};
for(;;)
{
    auto const c{cin.get()};
    auto const now{high_resolution_clock::now()};
    auto const char_repeats{c == last_char};
    auto const delay_is_small_enough{(now - last_input_time) < max_delay};
    //  TODO print key based on pressed char and repeats count...
    if(char_repeats && delay_is_small_enough)
    {
        ++repeats_count;
    }
    else
    {
        repeats_count = 0;
    }
    last_char = c;
    last_input_time = now;
}
```

Comment: Thank you VTT! I got it. But how should I start to code for program, handling inputs and outputting results. Sorry for these stupid questions cuz I'm complete new to C++ and don't know extreme simple tasks to do.